# Can we follow up our probation result?

Tags: professionalism, communication, work-environment, ethics, follow-up

So I've already worked for 3 months (probation), and today is the end of my probation. Well I haven't heard any result from HR / my boss (boss is in a different office because of corona) and I have never had a real talk with my boss (only in the first and second week from my job start date).

Now I'm curious because I haven't received any result. Should I follow up? Or the better question, is it ethical to ask about the probation result? Or should I wait? Because today is the end of my probation

Comment: You can ask, but in France for example if they do not say anything your probabation is validated

Comment: What result do you expect? What is in your contract? Doesn't the probation period simply end if you are not fired? In that case, no communication is a good sign.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the point of view of the company, the end of the probation period is just a flag day after which it will be more difficult to fire you.

There is an internal process that makes sure to ask your boss before that day if they should keep you on, but in most companies that is a formality, and if they wanted to fire you they would have done that way earlier.

So it seems all is fine.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can obviously ask.

Unless a specific date is given to you (that is in future, in a week or so) for any communication / update / meeting regarding the result, you should have already initiated the communication asking about the result and the next steps.

As you mentioned, due to COVID, many workflows are lagging, this may just be one of them. No harm in asking, ask away.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer sir , i will w8 for another answer before i accept it :D

Answer (score 1):

This is more related to contract than anything else. If you've signed a contract with a duration longer than your probation (or likely permanent), and the probation date has passed with no communication from your company, that usually means your probation is passed.

Since your company should fire you **before** your probation deadline expires, and it hasn't done so, it implicitly means you've passed the test. Often companies will not even recall the exact probation deadline in your contract, and only use it as a means to fire you if you really don't fit.

Of course, it is totally reasonable to tell your managers that your probation finished and that you would like to know if it was all OK. The answer to expect will probably be around the lines of "yes, you are still here, so you passed". There is no obligation on them to tell which specific criteria you've passed, or how they evaluated you.